# Segmentation fault (core dumped) copying form array to string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

char str[255] = "Hello;thisnewwolrd";

int i =0;
while(str[i] != ';')
{
   i++;
}
i++;

 char *name = NULL;
 while(str[i] != NULL)
{

  name[i] = str[i];
  i++;
    printf("%c \r\n",name[i]);
 }

}
```

the expected output is **thisnewwolrd** but i am getting error of core dumped 
canany one have reason why and how to over come this

Comment: You didn't allocate memory for `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
int main()
{
    char str[255] = "Hello;thisnewwolrd";
    char *ptr = strchr(str, ';') + 1;

    char name[255];
    strcpy( name, ptr);

    printf("%s \r\n", name);
}
```

You don't have to reinvent the wheel, and are much better off using standard library functions for string manipulation.

Comment: if i don't want use standard functions is their any otherway

Comment: @ganeshb you have made a few serious errors in a program of 10 lines long, getting "Segmentation fault" as a result, I think using standard functions is your safe bet until you get better and able to write good code. There's no shame in using training wheels if you keep falling off the bike.

Comment: ok any suggestion or link to learn and to improve my codes because i new to this in C

Comment: @ganeshb any beginner's book on C will do. I'd probably recommend to study C++ as well, because they are quite close and share a lot of concepts. And please, stay away from web sites with coding puzzles, like hackerank, because these sites encourage writing bad code.

Comment: do you have link of book or name  or some site for C and C++ if you provide the link of some website that will help full

Comment: i need help on above things

Comment: @ganeshb this is by no means an extensive list, but for web sites I'd start from https://www.learncpp.com/ and for books "C++ Primer" by Lippman is a good one. There are others as well, that may suit to your personal style, so try a few and see which works best. I'd recommend to use "Visual Studio Code" as an editor, it is freely available for download, works on Win / Linux / Mac and greatly helps in source code formatting and fixing simple typos.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate memory to store your string copy. For example: `char *name = malloc(255*sizeof(char));`.

And you have to create another iterator than `i` to start to fill the memory space pointed by `name` starting at the index 0.

Comment: You forgot to mention the problem with `i`

Comment: @ArdentCoder what problem ?

Comment: @Welgriv `i != 0` after the first loop, so the beginning of `name` becomes garbage